# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0]

Tags: nestjs

I'm implementing an API on NestJS that will consume another API, I'm using @nestjs/axios.

I followed this tutorial: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module

But when I start the project with `yarn start:dev`

It is throwing an exception as:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the HttpService (?). Please make sure that the argument AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN at index [0] is available in the AxelGlobeModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is a provider, is it part of the current AxelGlobeModule?
- If AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AxelGlobeModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN */ ]
  })
```

My app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    FileModule,
    ConfigurationModule,
    AxelGlobeModule,
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        timeout: configService.get('HTTP_TIMEOUT') || 1000,
        maxRedirects: configService.get('HTTP_MAX_REDIRECTS') || 5,
        baseURL: `{url}`,
        paramsSerializer: (params) => {
          return qs.stringify(
            params,
            PARAMS_SERIALIZER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS as IStringifyOptions,
          );
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, HttpModule, HttpService],
  exports: [HttpModule],
})
```

My axel-globe.module.ts

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AxelGlobeController],
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), HttpModule],
  providers: [AxelGlobeService, HttpService],
})
```

My service.ts

```
constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 12):

drop that `HttpService` of your `providers` list. You just need to import `HttpModule` in order to have `HttpService` provider available to use. Follow the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module#getting-started